# AVCaptureSession : adding/removing DeviceInput

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to implement a feature where you can enable or disable the microphone during a AVCaptureSession. This is how I enable the device (initialization)

```
-(void)initMicrophoneInput:(AVCaptureSession*)session{
    AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    _microphoneInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
    if ([session canAddInput:_microphoneInput]){
        [session addInput:_microphoneInput];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"can't add input");
    }
}
```

And this is my function for disabling/enabling the microphone :

```
- (IBAction)manageMicrophone:(id)sender {
    [_captureSession beginConfiguration];
    if(_microphoneMuted == NO){
        [_captureSession removeInput:_microphoneInput];
    }else{
        [self initMicrophoneInput:_captureSession];
    }
    [_captureSession commitConfiguration];
    _microphoneMuted = !_microphoneMuted;
}
```

Initialization and removing microphone works well, but then I can't enable the microphone again. My _captureSession.inputs contains the "micro" device but I don't get audio samples anymore from `- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;`

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: Tbh I stopped using AVCapture to capture audio. I will try again this afternoon if I have time

Comment: After few tests, unless I missed some hidden mute/un-mute function, you can't do that easily. I think the only way to get this feature is to prevent audio sample from being written by appendSampleBuffer(). Sadly if you do that, the "audio gap" (equivalent to the time spent with the microphone muted) will go at the end of your video, so you need to retime your CMSampleBufferRef

Comment: hmm .. though thanks for the effort!!